# How to run a script every 64 hours?

Tags: scripting, cron

I need to run a script every 64 hours. I couldn't find the answer with `cron`. Is it possible with it, or should I use a loop in a shell script?

Comment: Does your OS use systemd? If it does use systemd timer units: https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-schedule-tasks-with-systemd-timers-in-linux

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to schedule cronjob for every 45 days?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/442792/how-to-schedule-cronjob-for-every-45-days)

Comment: Cron doesn't bend to that too well directly. See [How to schedule cronjob for every 45 days?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/442792/170373) and [How to set cron job for every 5 hours](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/519538/170373) for some ways of dealing with it. Adjust for the desired time interval. (Ignore my answer to the first one, it won't help you here. The other ones would.)

Comment: May I ask why 64 hours specifically?

Comment: Can you tell us more about your use-case please?

Comment: Looking at this question a second time, it’s sounding to me like an XY problem. If we were to know _why_ it must be every 64 hours, we may be able to provide a solution that actually avoids that requirement altogether and better fits the required use case.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I suggest perhaps using a crontab "front end" like [crontab.guru](https://crontab.guru/) for figuring out crontab if you're a beginner.

However, as in your case, the hour setting only allows for values of 0 to 23, so you can't use crontab here.

Instead, I'd suggest using `at`. In your case, I'd probably use something like:

```sh
at now + 64 hours
```

and then enter your command or

```sh
echo "<your command>" | at now + 64 hours
```

at the beginning of your script, etc.
Basically, you'll be scheduling running the command right when the command has been invoked the last time. Also, if you don't want a time delta, rather the exact time, I suggest doing a bit of time arithmetic, and then use an exact time with `at` to have the command run.

I highly suggest reading [the man page of `at`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/at), as it is fairly comprehensive.

Comment: I'd suggest to add the new `at`-scheduling at the beginning of the script, otherwise a failure during script execution will also stop scheduling the next run.

Comment: crontab.guru is nice and pretty, but isn't worth anything for any of the special cases that cron can't directly do, but that crop up from time to time. Like intervals that don't divide cleanly into days or months, or running something on the first/last $weekday of a month.

Comment: @FelixJN That's actually a good idea, I've edited my answer using your suggestion.

Comment: @FelixJN: That also reduces the amount of timing error this will accumulate, but still not to zero.  A fraction of a second every 64 hours is trivial for most use-cases, but if it matters you could maybe round down to the start of the hour somehow, maybe parsing `data` output.  (More timing error can happen if the system is sometimes swap thrashing or mid reboot, or worse hibernated, when the `at` time comes. Big delay in commands running.)

Comment: On my *nix systems. "AT" only runs if the user is logged in to the machine at the time.

Answer (score 47):

Just run every hour and check that the number of hours since some arbitrary instant (for instance, instant 0 of the Unix epoch time) is a multiple of 64:

```
0 * * * * t=$(date +\%s); [ "$(( (t / 3600) \% 64 ))" -eq 0 ] && your-command
```

Comment: could check every 8 hours too (highest common factor of 24 and 64)

Comment: There is also the issue that `date %s` gives seconds in UTC and `cron` runs on local time. At DST changes a whole hour is erased or added to the local time. That should not be a problem here as the script is called "every hour", but worth noting for longer intervals.

Comment: @somebody, I did consider it doing it every 8 hours, but that wouldn't work in locales that implement DST. For instance in mainland UK and currently, that would have to be `0 0,8,16 * * *` in winter and `0 1,9,17 * * *` in summer.

Comment: @ImHere Late to the party, but wouldn't setting `TZ=UTC` above the entry in the crontab alleviate this?

Comment: @Griffin, by `crontab(5)` man page has in the `LIMITATIONS`  section: *Even if a user specifies the TZ environment variable in his crontab this will affect only the commands executed in the crontab, not the execution of the crontab tasks themselves.*. `date +%s` itself is independent on timezone.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas guess I'm missing something then. I thought the issue was that cron  and `date` were running on different time zones. Setting the crontab `TZ=UTC` would make the crontab run according to UTC (the same as `date`). :S

Comment: @Griffin A `4 3 * * *` will be executed at `03:04:00` **local** time, even with a TZ set for the crontab. Only the actual commands, like `date` here: `4 3 * * * date`, will be affected by such TZ environment variable.

Comment: bah my bad, I meant `CRON_TZ=UTC`

Comment: @Griffin, that looks like an extension of the *cronie* implementation of the cron system (a fork of the ISC's). It's not supported with the cron that ships with Debian or FreeBSD for instance.

Comment: This is a good answer - run the script every hour from cron, and then put the "is it time to run?" logic into the script.  It would help to know more about OP's use case, perhaps there's an input file that can be checked for age, or a log file that has to be at least 63 hours old before the script should run its main tasks.

Comment: This is the correct answer to the OPs question. at is not a periodic service and no amount of pure crontab schedules will do it, but with a little extra logic, it's not too hard.

Answer (score 26):

`cron` is made to run things on date or clock events, i.e. every 1st of a month or week or every third hour of a day, respectively.

For running things in time intervals that cannot be simply expressed by arithmetics on clock time or dates, I'd suggest using a `systemd` timer - which of course works only if you have `systemd` running on your respective device.

You will need two files, the service file to run the script and the timer file for managing the events.

```
$cat /etc/systemd/system/myscript.service

[Unit]
Description=this service runs my script

[Service]
ExecStart=/full/path/to/myscript.sh

#[Install]
#WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

This service simply executes the script without checking if it succeeded or anything. Optionally enable the service via `systemctl enable myscript.service` which means it will be executed once during boot time - I commented this out, because the timer will take care of boot events. You may manually run your script by `systemctl start myscript.service`.

---

```
$cat /etc/systemd/system/myscript.timer

[Unit]
Description=this timer runs myscript.service every 64h

[Timer]
OnBootSec=120
OnUnitActiveSec=64h


[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

This is the timer to run the `myscript.service` every 64h since the last activation of the service as well as two minutes after boot time (to ensure that the system is in the right state for the service to run).
Note that the timer will **not** remember the 64h if you reboot/power off. Enable and start the timer accordingly:

```
systemctl enable myscript.timer
systemctl start myscript.timer
```

Since the timer only starts after a boot or since the last unit activation, you will have to run the service once to ensure the timer runs:

```
systemctl start myscript.service
```

Check the status of the timers by

```
systemctl list-timers
```

Comment: Also, consider `OnActiveSec=` instead of `OnUnitActiveSec=` if you don't want the timer to be dependent on when the unit was last run, e.g. if you want the timer to run every 64h even if you manually run the unit at other times.

Comment: Also, using a fixed 120s timer to try to "ensure that the system is in the right state" is a bad idea. Use [`After=`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#Before=) with [`Wants=`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#Wants=) or [`Requires=`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#Requires=) to more explicitly specify dependencies so that you *know* when they are available, rather than guessing 120s is enough in all situations.

Comment: @Bob Agreed regarding `After=` etc.. Be careful: `Persistent=true` only applies to events scheduled with `OnCalendar`, a missed 64h-interval via `On(Unit)ActiveSec` will **not** be accounted for. See [official documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.timer.html)

Comment: Ah, I had missed that line. Good point! I'll delete my other comment to avoid confusion. That does restrict options, then, since `OnCalendar=` runs into the same problems cron does -- leaving your post-boot catchup the best option if it must run on boot.

Answer (score 6):

64 hours is 2 and 2/3 days, so 3 * 64 hours = 192 hours = 8 days. So you could *almost* do

```
0 0  1-25/8 * * foo
0 16 3-27/8 * * foo
0 8  6-30/8 * * foo
```

except that you get a short pattern at the end of the month (if the month has 30 days, then there will be only 16 hours between the run at 08:00 on the 30th and the one at 00:00 on the 1st; if the month has 31 days, it will be 40 hours; if the month has 28 days, it will be 32 hours between the run at 16:00 on the 27th and the one at 00:00 on the 1st; if the month has 29 days, it will be 56), and also things will be off by 1 hour whenever your locality goes on or comes off of summer time (assuming it does).

Doesn't quite meet your specs (and I endorse any of the other answers that do), but it *is* an interesting exercise in making do.

Answer (score 0):

Surprised no one has mentioned either of:-

**Anacron**

It's supplied as standard on most distro's.