# Sheduling a shell script using crontabs for a rolling 5 hour interval across days

Tags: linux, cron, date

I need to schedule a shell script execution with crontabs to execute it every 5 hours starting from 01:00 and daily. 
sample execution times:

2020-05-29 01:00

2020-05-29 06:00

2020-05-29 11:00

2020-05-29 16:00

2020-05-29 21:00

2020-05-30 02:00

2020-05-30 07:00
.....

please note that the interval is rolled forward per the day.

I have tried the following expression but crontab is giving an error saying "bad hour".

```
0 1/5 * * * path_to_shell_script
```

Can anyone suggest a way accomplish this if it is possible with crontabs?

Comment: The main difference being this request to "roll" the interval forward per-day, not be at the same hours every day.

Comment: Would also strongly suggest not using sh on the crontab command.  Cron generally runs sh itself, and it then honours your shebang and runs the shell you expect it to be. If you explicitly run sh, that sh process will read your script, ignore the shebang, ignore permissions, and run your script in /bin/sh.

Comment: no @steeldriver. the problem with that is as same as Akhil's answer below

Comment: exactly yes it is @JeffSchaller

Comment: Relating https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/519553/117549

Comment: Yes, @JeffSchaller, that solves the problem up to most of the extent except what happens on the last day of months which doesn't have multiple of five days. thank you.

Comment: thanks, @Paul_Pedant. I have amended the command.

Comment: See: [Setting up a cron for every 30 hours in Debian](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/119053/170373) and [How to schedule cronjob for every 45 days?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/442792/170373)  ([Jeff's A](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/442803/170373), not mine.)

Comment: You might want to check on this https://crontab.guru/#*_*_*_*

Comment: @annahri, crontab.guru doesn't really help.

Comment: @ThilankaD, I added [another answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/589931/170373) in the identical-ish Q Jeff linked to [How to set cron job for every 5 hours](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/519538/170373)